# Total chemical potential of electrons in pn junction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, semiconductor-physics, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

I am reading [this](http://sjbyrnes.com/fermiterminology.html) page about electron energy concept terminology.

I am trying to apply that for the pn junction in equilibrium below.

Could anyone help me to see if I get it correctly?

C = Electric potential = built-in potential

B = Internal chemical potential of electrons = 0

(because Fermi level is constant through the junction)

A = Total chemical potential of electrons = B + C = built-in potential

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You said "Fermi level is constant throughout the junction" - that's correct. But fermi level is "A" (see top right in the table). So A is constant (you can set it to zero if you like). B is not constant.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Could you tell me what is B in this case? If it is not constant then B is not zero so what is wrong here?

Comment: Also, could you comment about the answer of Prof. Rehan Kapadia on the page? 

https://www.quora.com/Semiconductors-Why-cant-the-built-in-potential-across-the-depletion-region-of-a-p-n-diode-be-measured-externally

There are two problem I am confused relating to the answer:
1. Why did he say that all the answers relating to contact potential are incorrect?
2. If I understood him correctly, in pn junction the Fermi level is same everywhere so the voltage meaaused will be always zero regardless of whether there are contact potential or not.
Is this right?

Comment: You said B is zero. But it's not. You didn't say why you believe B to be zero, so I can't explain "what is wrong" in any detail.

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86843/pn-junction-voltage-drop/86860#86860

Comment: Thank you. From the description above, B seems to be the difference in work function of n and p semiconductor. But I am confused about the Fermi level in A and Fermi level in B. What is the difference between them?
I infer that the Fermi level in B is the Fermi energy level when p and n semiconductor haven't brought together in contact while the Fermi level in A is the Fermi energy level when they are in contact. Am I correct?

Comment: Fermi level is constant throughout the junction.

Comment: Thanks. But when n and p semiconductor haven't brought into contact then the Fermi levels of the two are not equal and constant. Is this right?

Comment: If n and p semiconductors have not been brought into contact, then it is not a p-n junction. This question you asked here is about a p-n junction. If you are now interested in a different kind of device, then you should ask a new question.