# Can we observe the p-n Junction voltage Drop?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, semiconductor-physics

The question is in the title, to clarify: I know that in a P-N-junction, at the boundary, there is going to be a voltage drop in thermal equilibrium. I also know that we can't measure this voltage drop by measuring the potential difference over the whole semiconductor device: If the diode is in thermal equilibrium, and we clamp a voltmeter to the endpoints of the diode, we will measure zero voltage.

But has at anytime somebody anyhow actually observed the voltage drop inside the diode, right at the pn-junction? Or is it just assumed that diode's work this way, because the model yields fine results and can explain the current-voltage behaviour of the diode?

What I imagined was a measurement that gives specific values of the potential inside the diode, at specific points in the diode, shown graphically in an $\Phi$ vs $x$ Diagramm, where x is the spatial distance in the junction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pn junction voltage drop?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86843/)

Comment: Well ... no. The question you mention deals with why there is no net current, although there is a drop. I just want to know if the drop has been measured. Has somebody ever measured the actual potential (modulo constant) inside the diode, right at the junction?

Comment: Like the open-circuit voltage of a solar cell (which is just a diode)? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the voltage drop across by measuring the voltage required to make a current flow in the forward biased direction.

If you measure the current as a function of voltage for a forward bias you get something like:

[image: V-I curve]

([image is from this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234677/why-the-current-across-a-diode-is-zero-when-the-forward-bias-voltage-is-less-tha))

The knee voltage ($0.65 - 0.7$V in this case) is a measurement of the potential across the junction.

Comment: But there is no measurement of the actual potential inside the diode? Like a function $\phi(x)$ ?