# Why diodes can be used to create a current-independent voltage drop?

Tags: electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

How is current independent of the voltage drop in a diode?

Comment: Are you referring to the turn-on voltage of a diode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pn junction voltage drop?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86843/)

Answer (score 0):

> How is current independent of the voltage drop in a diode?

This is a simplification. For instance, at zero voltage, the current of a diode would be zero.

In general, the current of a diode grows exponentially with the forward voltage. Because of that, a small relative change of the forward voltage can result in a large relative change of the current.

Since in many applications the current of a diode changes in a relatively narrow range, the corresponding forward voltage appears to be almost constant.

As an example, the diagram below shows typical IV curves for LED's.

[image]

In most practical applications, the current for these LED's would be somewhere between $4$mA and $8$mA, a $2$x range, which corresponds to the forward voltage change of less than $5$%, which may create an impression that the current does not depend on the voltage. Yet, the same IV curves show that at $1$V, the LED current is measured in microamps.

In summary, the current of a diode does depend on the forward voltage, but, since the relative change of the forward voltage is typically much smaller than the relative change of the current, we can approximate the forward voltage as a constant voltage drop, which would depend on the type of a diode and on the current range for a given application.

Answer (score 0):

The 'voltage on a diode' can be nearly constant if you establish the operating
current and polarity of a Zener or avalanche
breakdown diode, OR if you feed a nearly-constant current to the
diode in its forward biased polarity.

For an ideal PN junction diode in forward bias, which measures 0.600V
at 1 mA current, you can expect 0.620V at 2 mA current at room temperature.   Sometimes,
that's close enough to 'constant'.   It's a lot better than a
resistor, at .600V with 1 mA, which measures 1.200V at 2 mA.

More complex circuitry, matching a resistor divider output to a
resistor-diode output (a kind of Wheatstone bridge with one
nonlinear diode element), can be stabilized with a feedback
amplifier to make a very accurate voltage reference (limited
mainly by the temperature dependence of the diode voltage).
Such a bridge-amplifier reference regulates the bias current
through the diode, either forward or reverse biased.

And, a third scheme (using multiple diodes with different current
denities) can (because of the predictable forward-voltage
curve of an ideal diode) generate constant voltage without
significant temperature dependence (this is 
generally called a bandgap reference).

All of these schemes are in widespread use, and it is rare to
find any accurate 'voltage source' which does not use a
semiconductor diode as its reference voltage.